# How to return results (done in another workbook) to the original workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a "update" button in workbook1, then it requests user to locate the excel file, the the opened workbook would run `RunCode()`, summarizing data and its result is saved at Range A200:D256

I know I have missed the code for the opened `workbook(=workbook2)`, like dim XXXXXX

Please help I have no idea how to dim?

**Here is the code:**

```
Sub Button1_Click()

  Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
  Set sourceSheet = ActiveSheet

' Create and set the file dialog object.
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With fd
        .Filters.Clear      ' Clear all the filters

        ' Give the dialog box a title, word for doc or Excel for excel files
        .Title = "Select an Excel File"

        ' Apply filter to show only a particular type of files
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls?", 1

        ' Do not allow users to select more than one file
        ' Set the value as "True" to select multiple files
        .AllowMultiSelect = False

        ' Show the file.
        If .Show = True Then
           Workbooks.Open Filename:=.SelectedItems(1)
           Debug.Print .SelectedItems(1)

           Call RunCode
        End If
    End With

    Call sourceSheet.Activate

    Dim lasRow As Long
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

End Sub
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: check spelling `lasRow As Long` Should be `lastRow As Long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to the opened workbook if you use something like:

```
Dim wbk as workbook
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open Filename:=.SelectedItems(1)
```

You can obtain the summerized data as:

```
wbk.worksheets("sheetname").range("A200:D256").copy
thisworkbook.worksheets("sheetname").range("first cell to copy to").pastespecial (xlpasteall)
```

Instead of worksheets("sheetname"), you could also use worksheets(sheetnumber) or Activesheet. Instead of pastespecial (XlPasteAll) you could use pastespecial (XlPasteValues), what suits best for you.